# Does the app need to act differently on messages received with and without delivery_receipt_requested in FCM?

Tags: android, xmpp, firebase-cloud-messaging

According to the [Firebase Cloud Messaging documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/server) if the app server sets a field "delivery_receipt_requested" in the upstream message, it will receive a delivery confirmation when the app confirms receipt. However it works only if app server is connected with XMPP connection server. It will not work for HTTP connection server.

I'm very new to GCM/FCM and haven't setup my server yet. Hence am working with Firebase console to test my app for notification receipts.

So, following are my queries.

1. Will the field "delivery_receipt_requested" be sent to the app or the connection server itself will consume it.?
2. If the app receives this field in a notification will it need to act differently from the notification which do not contain this field.?

Any references to documentation or example implementation which makes use of this field is highly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Will the field "delivery_receipt_requested" be sent to the app or the connection server itself will consume it.?

The FCM client installed in Google Play services will handle this.
The application will not notice anything different.

> If the app receives this field in a notification will it need to act differently from the notification which do not contain this field.?

The application doesn't need to take any action. indeed the app will not receive this field.

---

**Longer explanation**:

1. `delivery_receipt` is not exactly a confirmation that the app received the message, but **it's a confirmation that the device received the message.** To be clear it's still possible that the device crashed or run out of battery while the message is being passed to the app.
2. this feature is implemented outside of the application. so the application doesn't need to be aware that this message requires a delivery receipt
3. you can implement a more precise "application delivery receipt" by calling your backend in the method that receives the message.
   (like an http call to: `http://mywebsite.com/confirm-msg-processed-successfully.php?id=133`)